# TBXML parsing complex xml into array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I have an xml response that i need to set into an array. The problem is i need to access each element and store it in an array so that i can use it for a tableview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.2sms.com/2.0/schema/0310_ResponseReportStandard.xsd" Version="1.0">
    <Error>
        <ErrorCode>00</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorReason>OK</ErrorReason>
    </Error>
    <ResponseData>
        <Identification>
            <UserID>jonathan.pink@2sms.com</UserID>
        </Identification>
        <Result>2 records were returned</Result>
        <Detail>
            <ReportTitle>Message Summary: Today</ReportTitle>
            <Record>
                <Destination>447790686158</Destination>
                <Status>WithNetwork</Status>
                <GUID><![CDATA[2011-03-22T10:54:22.097Z]]></GUID>
                <DateSubmitted>2011-03-22T10:54:22.097</DateSubmitted>
                <DateToSend></DateToSend>
                <DateSent>2011-03-22T10:54:22.533</DateSent>
                <DateReceived></DateReceived>
                <Message><![CDATA[Yet again another test]]></Message>
                <ID>2011-03-22 10:54:22.250HIHIIOJTFVETW85TS</ID>
            </Record>
            <Record>
                <Destination>447790686158</Destination>
                <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
                <GUID><![CDATA[2011-03-22T10:50:40.064Z]]></GUID>
                <DateSubmitted>2011-03-22T10:50:40.063</DateSubmitted>
                <DateToSend></DateToSend>
                <DateSent>2011-03-22T10:50:42.473</DateSent>
                <DateReceived>2011-03-22T10:50:54.570</DateReceived>
                <Message><![CDATA[This is a test]]></Message>
                <ID>2011-03-22 10:50:40.210DRUDVMCEZGETW85TS</ID>
            </Record>
            <ReportPage ReportID="775797" ItemsPerPage="25" Page="1" TotalItems="2" />
        </Detail>
    </ResponseData>
</Response>
```

I have the TBXML object initialised but can't work out how to get any of the recurring information, I know it will need some sort of loop but i'm pretty new to objective-c so its proving a challenge.

I need to get the `<destination> , <status>, <datesent>, <message>` from the xml. There can be up to 25 records....

Hope some one can help this has been doing my head in all day!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did something similar recently that you can adapt quickly, my XML was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<agencies>
    <agency>
        <name>Agency 1 name</name>
        <addressFirstLine>Immeuble XYZ<addressFirstLine>
        <addressSecondLine>rue de la republique</addressSecondLine>
        <addressThirdLine>69007 Lyon</addressThirdLine>
        <telNumber>01 23 45 67 89</telNumber>
    </agency>
    <agency>
        <name>Agency 2 name</name>
        <addressFirstLine>Immeuble ABC<addressFirstLine>
        <addressSecondLine>rue de la republique</addressSecondLine>
        <addressThirdLine>69007 Lyon</addressThirdLine>
        <telNumber>01 23 45 67 89</telNumber>
    </agency>
</agencies>
```

The code I used to parse this (get the result in my `NSArray` called `agencies`):

```
    TBXML *tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLFile:yourXmlFile retain];
    TBXMLElement *rootXMLElement = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

    if (rootXMLElement) {
        self.agencies = [self traverseElement:rootXMLElement];
        [delegate managerDidReceiveData];
    }

    // release resources
    [tbxml release];
```

And my fonction to convert in array:

```
- (NSArray *)traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element {

    NSMutableArray *tmpAgencies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    TBXMLElement *agenciesXmlElement = element->firstChild;
    TBXMLElement *agencyXmlElement;

    do {

        // if the element has child elements, process them
        if ((agencyXmlElement = agenciesXmlElement->firstChild)) {

            NSMutableDictionary *tmpAgency = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            do {
                [tmpAgency setValue:[TBXML textForElement:agencyXmlElement] forKey:[TBXML elementName:agencyXmlElement]];

            // Obtain next sibling element
            } while ((agencyXmlElement = agencyXmlElement->nextSibling));

            [tmpAgencies addObject:tmpAgency];
            [tmpAgency release];
        }

    // Obtain next sibling element
    } while ((agenciesXmlElement = agenciesXmlElement->nextSibling));

    return tmpAgencies;
}
```

This function will return you an array which contains `NSDictionary` objects representing your `Records`.
NSDictionary is simple to use, to get a property you use `[yourDictionary objectForKey:yourXmlNode]`. The doc is here: [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I've implemented this but the array i get only fills with the anything beyond the second level...

Comment: I have only two levels in my sample XML, agenciesXmlElement->firstChild is getting the second level. You have to do this again to go deeply in the levels. You have everything here to do it, just **adapt** it.

Comment: Great answer! But just in case - for n level deepness - https://gist.github.com/romainbriche/1922643 returns dictionary.